# Delete data object on Backendless

Tags: backendless

I recently started working with BackendLess. I am making use of the database service. I was wondering if it is possible to delete an entry based on other values, other than `objectId`. If not, how is it possible to retrieve the `objectId`? Is it possible to be queried in c\some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete objects without knowing `objectId` with the conditional deletion API call, it is also known as 'bulk delete' (scroll down the page):
https://backendless.com/docs/rest/doc.html#data_deleting_data_objects

To retrieve `objectId` though, you can run a find API call where you retrieve objects with some condition as well:
https://backendless.com/docs/rest/doc.html#data_search_and_query

Comment: How would these APIs be used in Javascript?

Comment: the bulk deletion API is available only with REST. The following question on SO has some examples of how to call REST APIs from JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript-button-handler