# Can babylonjs communicate with a REST endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, babylonjs, blender-2.67

I am trying to develop a 3D UI with babylon. This UI is expected to communicate with some ReST endpoints. Basically clicking on certain points of the scene should make some ReST calls like get, post, put etc and accordingly some more sub scenes be displayed. Any leads to simple examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, although I'd say that the two aren't really related. BabylonJS is the graphics library which allows you interact with Canvas and WebGL via JavaScript. Separately there are plenty of options to make REST requests via vanilla JavaScript (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript)). So you'd be using JavaScript to code both your graphics and the REST requests. The way in which you combine the two is up to you!

Maybe start looking at https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/how_to_use_actions. That suggests you can hook up any JS code (your REST request for example) based on a trigger action.