# Post from HTML to a separate .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, html

We followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1 Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio for Windows and created a ToDoApi project. I can post & get through the project and through PostMan to URL: http://localhost:2399/api/todo

Then, I created new project using ASP.NET Web Forms Site.
I added new Web Form with this html:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="http://localhost:2399/api/Create">
        <div>
            <asp:Label  Text="Name:" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="name"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server"  />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I tried to post to previous project but wasn't successful. I can hit the first breakpoint but not the second. We want the .NET Core to be the back end API and the HTML form as a front end. What do you recommend?

[image]

```
  public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [Route("~/api/Create")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] TodoItem item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
```

Simple form call the api (this is not working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MY API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ADD NEW LEAD</h1>
        <input type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="Full Name">
        <input type="text" id="add-company" placeholder="Company">
        <input type="text" id="add-phone" placeholder="Phone">
        <input type="text" id="add-email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" id="add-address" placeholder="Address">
        <input type="text" id="add-city" placeholder="City">
        <input type="text" id="add-state" placeholder="State">
        <input type="text" id="add-zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
        <input type="text" id="add-description" placeholder="Description">

        <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:send()">Submit</button>


    <div id='div'>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function send() {
            //var ItemJSON = {
            //    "FullName": $('#add-name').val(),
            //    "Company": $('#add-company').val(),
            //    "Phone": $('#add-phone').val(),
            //    "Email": $('#add-email').val(),
            //    "Address": $('#add-address').val(),
            //    "City": $('#add-city').val(),
            //    "State": $('#add-state').val(),
            //    "Zip": $('#add-zip').val(),
            //    "Description": $('#add-description').val()
            //};
            var ItemJSON = '{    "FullName": "NA", "Phone": "31439289452", "Ext": "5000",  "Email": "m.alkurwi@Yahoo.com","Company": "PlazSoft", "Address": "357 Hinder dr",  "Description": "tsetteststeste",   "City": "STL",    "State": "MO",  "Zipcode": "63125"  }';
            alert('1')
            URL = "http://localhost:59930/api/values";  //Your URL

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    alert(this.responseText);
                }
            };
            alert('2')
            xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, true);//tried both false and true
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(ItemJSON));
            document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText + ":" + xmlhttp.status + "<BR><textarea rows='100' cols='100'>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "</textarea>";
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Post man can POST to it, but the web form can't

Comment: don't mix webforms into this - it is really tied for interoperating w/ the webforms backend.

Comment: We want the .NET Core to be the back end API and the HTML form as a front end. What do you recommend?

Comment: just use straight html - no `runat` crap.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose the right client technology**

According your question level I suggest you to start with a plain html site (learn from here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) with some js. Maybe also use jquery (http://jquery.com/), it makes your life easier for the first steps. This way you will learn the basics.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

I personally think this are elementar basics which you should understand. After that you can make a step forward and learn for example angular.

(Hint Its very simple to call your rest service with JS. See for example here:
[How to call a REST web service API from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript))

Comment: See update: Simple form call the api (this is not working).