# How do I pull JSON data from API displaying in plain text?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to pull specific information such as `name`, `downloadCount` etc from this API so I can display them as text on my website, but it is all formatted as a 
wall of plain text rather than a json file I can just pull from the url.

URL: https://staging_cursemeta.dries007.net/api/v3/direct/addon/268210

How should I go forward with pulling data and how shall I access specific fields from this kind of APIs.
I am using JavaScript.

Comment: It's a valid JSON file not "a wall of plain text" as you said

Comment: This kind of question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript See if that helps you.

Comment: it is actually a JSON data.

Comment: you can make HTTP Get request to retrieve all data inside that file.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a JSON like structure in text format to JSON, you need [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`{
 "description": "lorem ipsum",
 "error": true,
 "status": 404
}`);

console.log(data.status);
```