# Is it possible to create a complete website only using Django REST Framework(DRF) and Bootstrap only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, frontend, bootstrap-5

I'm a new back-end developer and I want to create a simple shopping website. I have an API created in Django REST Framework. I want to use Bootstrap 5 as the front-end. My question is, whether these tools enough for building my website, or do I need more tools?

Answer (score 1):

You may call API through Javascript, for further details I found the following to be useful:

- [Call REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600060/how-to-call-rest-api-in-html/54600143)
- [DRF HTML and Forms](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/)