# How to use GET/POST methods to interact with minehutAPI/server

Tags: javascript, http, post, get

I have started with the minehut API, and after looking at the docs ([see a copy here](https://minehut-api-doc.glitch.me)) it uses get and post. 
As a newbie to javascript etc I dont know how it works.

---

**Part 1 - Get Info**

for example: I want to get info about a server, it says to use `GET https://api.minehut.com/server/{server-id}`
How would i get for example playercount from it so that i can give that info to my code and display it on my website.
`Required headers:` is also mentioned in the docs, what are these and how do i use them?

**Part 2 - send info**

Now say for example i want to run a command, the docs say to use `POST /server/{Server ID}/send_command`. It also mentions Required headers saying it needs
`Content-Type`,
`Authorization` and
`x-session-id` 
how would i send a string so that it would use POST to run a command

Comment: I think you are trying to call a API from using ajax. For that you can use jQuery or simple JavaScript. By default Header have content-type of json which could work for you. Here is a link to learn how to make a ajax call
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: it returns `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` when using `var info = $.ajax({` then without the `$` it says `TypeError: ajax is not a function` @AliKhan

Comment: have you included jquery library in your code? this is happening because you have not included jquery in your project. You can include that with a direct cdn and also can download the files and include then in your project. you can find documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: So is there a way that i can then add this to some code in node.js code? as i have a discord bot that runs from node.js that i will use to trigger the get() @AliKhan

Comment: jQuery is related to front end so i cannot be used with node js but there are ways to generate a API call in simple javascript. Fr refrence plese see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript

Comment: you are welcome. please up vote comments if you find them useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to send or receive data using GET/POST methods is XMLHttpRequest object.

```js
var server_id = "EXAMPLE_ID";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4){
        // Data sent back available in this.responseText
        // For example:
        var recData = this.responseText;
        // further handling
    }
}
req.open('GET', 'https://api.minehut.com/server/' + server_id, true);
req.send();
```

Or in case of POST request:

```js
req.open('POST', 'https://api.minehut.com/server/' + server_id + '/send_command', true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "pplication/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass));
req.setRequestHeader("HeaderNameExample", "ItsValueExample");
req.send('optionalVar=sentData&foo=bar&etc");
```

In some cases preflight request can be done (especially with custom request headers) and the request might fail. To avoid that you might try invoking the opening with user/password instead. For cross domain request Access-Controll request should be made which allows for cookies to be set.

```js
req.open("GET", url, true, username, password);

req.open("POST", url, true, username, password);

req.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: so what would i set as `Authorization` and `x-session-id`.