# Can I communicate with another website with <script>?

Tags: html

I am working on a project where it communicates with a sites servers with a couple lines of HTML code, so I need a piece of code that sends a query or just does something with the separate website .

What have I tried? Well I have tried looking online but I didn't really find anything. And the code? I didn't try anything, I have no idea how to do it.

My code:

I said I didn't know how to do it, so there is no code.

Thanks for answering if you answered!

(If there are other programming languages involved, I don't mind)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a REST web service API from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to API from website which you want to use in your project.