# Pass a complex object from window.open to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a javascript functionality of passing complex data from window.open() to MVC Controller action method parameter.
I was able to achieve it by constructing a query string and retrieving them from [FromQuery] in controller.

But my problem is I want to pass the data as a model object. Is it possible in window.open()

Below is my javascript code

```
$("#btnExportToExcelForBatch").on('click',
                function() {
                    var currentBatchId = 0;
                    var empName = $("#empName").val();
                    var empId = $("#empId").val();
                    var deptId = $("#deptId").val();
                    window.open("/Download/ExportToExcel?EmpName="
                        + empName + "&EmpId=" + empId + "&DeptId="
                        + deptId);                 
                });
```

As you can see, I can pass the data in the URL, but it seems to be exposed. So, is there way that I can pass in 

 `var url = @Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Download");`

But I am unable to pass them.

Is there a possible way to achieve by sending as model object to MVC controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportToExcel(EmployeeModel employeeModel)
{
     // SomeCode
     return File();
}
```

Could anyone help me with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have couple of options here. You can either generate the query string and then send it to `window.open` but your parameters would be exposed in this case:

```
var urlquerstr = BaseUrl + "/Download/ExportToExcel?EmpName="+ empName + "&EmpId=" + empId+ "&DeptId="+ deptId;
```

Equivalent using `Url.Action`:

```
var urlquerstr = @Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Download", new { EmpName= Model.empName, EmpId= Model.empId, DeptId=Model.deptId })
```

Once you have generated your query string, then you can simply do:

```
window.open(urlquerstr);
```

OR you are looking to `POST` your parameters to your `Controller` method and based on that take an appropriate action. You can do this using `AJAX`. Specific to your case:

```
$("#btnExportToExcelForBatch").on('click',
   function() {
      var currentBatchId = 0;
      var empName = $("#empName").val();
      var empId = $("#empId").val();
      var deptId = $("#deptId").val();
      //Generate data to be sent to the controller
      var json= { EmpName: empName , EmpId: empId , DeptId: deptId };
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Download")',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},
    success: function (result) {
         alert(result);
         //window.open(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
         console.log(error)
    }
  });                
});
```

And your `Controller` method would look like:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]    
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportToExcel(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    //Get your variables here from AJAX call
    var EmpName= jsondata["EmpName"];
    var EmpId=jsondata["EmpId"];
    var DeptId=jsondata["DeptId"];

    //Do something with your variables here    

    return Json("File exported successfully");
}
```

If you want to use `URL.Action` with Javascript parameters:

```
'@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Download")?EmpName=' + empName + '&EmpId=' + empId '&DeptId=' + deptId;
```

Please note that you would have to call this in a javascript function.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. I've tried it using Url.Action(), but while giving object values, it is throwing error `empName is not in current context`

Comment: @Vijay Sorry it should be `Model.empName` and similar for rest of the values.

Comment: `empName,empId,deptId` aren't Model property, they are created in JS. So, if I keep `@Model.empName`, it throws error

Comment: @Vijay Then you can either go the `AJAX` method (preferred) or you can send the parameters as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: haven't tried using ajax. Will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You have to put employeeModel parameter value as json body when accessing the `/Download/ExportToExcel`

The problem is that `ExportToExcel` method must be used with POST or PUSH action to pass the Json parameter value in the request body.

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript) for details