# Why is my fetch command not passing the body to AWS API Gateway?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, fetch, aws-api-gateway

I have a stage in AWS API Gateway that takes `POST` requests. If I call this API Gateway with Postman, everything works as expected. I can see in CloudWatch logs, that the body of the POST is present. The body is as follows (shortened):

```
{
    "Success": "1",
    "Item": {
        "IngameName": "SomeName",
        "Timestamp": "Mon Oct 12 2020 19:07:29 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)"
    }
}
```

I also set a header for the content type in Postman: `Content-Type : application/json`.

I try to make the same call again using `fetch` in JavaScript:

```
let testJson = {
    "Success": "1",
    "Item": {
        "IngameName": "SomeName",
        "Timestamp": "Mon Oct 12 2020 19:07:29 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)"
    }
};
fetch(apiGatewayAddressLocal, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(testJson),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

The `fetch` call reaches API Gateway successfully, but CloudWatch logs say that the body is empty. I have also tried doing `json.parse` instead of `json.stringify` but this gives me `Unexpected token` errors in the console. I saw some solutions including `Accept:application/json` as a header, which I tried but does not fix the solution. I also tried the [solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51854096/7062012), but then I could not reach API Gateway at all.

I have double checked that `apiGatewayAddressLocal` definitely contains a valid link, it is the same as I used in Postman

Why is my `fetch` call not passing any body to API Gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was happening because the `fetch` command was not included inside an `async` function, and the `fetch` command needed to be used with `await`. I also added in a `no-cors` mode with the `fetch` operation.

```
async function someFunction(callback) {
    let testJson = {
        "Success": "1",
        "Item": {
            "IngameName": "SomeName",
            "Timestamp": "Mon Oct 12 2020 19:07:29 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)"
        }
    };
    await fetch(apiGatewayAddressLocal, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(testJson)
    });
    callback();
}
```