# How to read data from Microsoft Graph using a get request?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

My goal is to read the data inside an Excel at azure with some get request.
I am trying to get the JSON contain the information form one of my Excel files.
I am using the "Excel: used range in worksheet", it can be found in the page "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer".
In the get query area it says the query is: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/usedRange`.
After changing the {drive-item-id} and the Sheet1 for correct values it gives me an error or authentication:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2021-06-09T16:26:24","request-id":"60912689-40d7-4f84-ba3b-d2350d121044","client-request-id":"60912689-40d7-4f84-ba3b-d2350d121044"}}}
```

Is it possible to just add the access token to it and get all the data from the file?
For example:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/usedRange?token=12345678`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add the access token directly to the request URL, you need to add it to the [request header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-usedrange?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-headers) as `Authorization:Bearer <access token>`(don't miss the space) when you call the API.

You can also call the API in the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), in it don't need to add the token manually, just sign the explorer and click `Modify permissions` to add [`Files.ReadWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-usedrange?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) delegated permission, then you can call the API.

[image]

Comment: When I open that it is ok, but I mean I need to open with a script, using or php or javascript. So that is why I cannot go to that page every time, but I want to perform the actions that exist in that page

Comment: @HygisonBrandao Of course, you can, just add the token to the request header as I mentioned.

Comment: Could you tell me the link then? like, what should I change here: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/usedRange?token=12345678

Comment: @HygisonBrandao Just follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript) to make the API call, add `'Authorization': 'Bearer <access token>'` to the headers, also remove `?token=12345678` in the url.