# How do I run a Python function in Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, web

I am using Python for backend and web scraping, and JavaScript for frontend to write a website. My python file is as below.

```
def fn1(param1, param2, param3):
  .......

def fn2(param1, param2, param3):
  .......
```

I want to call fn2() specifically within my js file's function and get a returned value. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a few key concepts here.

What you're asking at the moment isn't really possible (To call your backend  Python function within your `JavaScript` file).

What is possible is using REST apis to interact with your `Python` backend from `JavaScript`.

You can use python frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) to create backend `Python` APIS.

I suggest you do a bit of reading on REST, as it's the bread and butter for interacting with backends via front end web applications. [Here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understanding-restful-api-with-flask-59421f01f648) is a good introduction to REST while using the `Flask` framework.

I think if you work your way through the above, then read about how to interact with API's via `JavaScript`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript) stackoverflow answer here is a great resource on it.

Comment: I do agree implementing REST in the strictest sense _should_ be centred around states and entities. But it sounds like OP is relatively new to programming. I think the simplest way for him to achieve what he wants is to just setup a simple REST API, and return the data as JSON to display in his frontend.

Comment: I don't disagree that RPC wouldn't solve the problem, I just think that for a newer developer RPC isn't the most friendly thing to wrap your head around. For someone newer to the field and considering it's a front end interacting with a backend, I think REST is a simpler and less daunting solution. 

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, you can spawn a `subprocess`. You can write Python code to a file with `fs` and then run it with commands, eg `py foo.py`.

In regular JavaScript, you can't run Python unless you somehow manage to write a Python parser/interpreter in JavaScript. Otherwise, you just rely on a backend to run Python code.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you can't really mix languages (css and html don't count as languages for this one). You'd have to re-write parts of your code :/