# How can I implement frontend in API without using a framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

hope you are having a great day.
I will get straight to the point, I have an application in Spring. I am using API calls from postman to retrieve my data.
Now I am asked to implement a front-end but without a framework, I was told that only ajax and javascript should do the trick.
How would I be able to implement this?
Keep in mind it is not an MVC application, but rather an API.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Several ways of doing so ! You can use**

1. Javascript
2. Jquery
3. Angular JS

**Check if below article helps**
[How to call a REST web service API from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript)